# How to add music to C#?

Tags: c#, audio

I'm new at programming and I'm trying to program out a snake game. I've been trying to program sounds or music into the game but to no avail.
For instance, I'd like to have a "boop" sound every time the snake eats an apple and I'd like a short music clip every time I get to a new level. I've already added the wav files of the clips into the resources but it still doesn't work.

This is part of the codes that I tried to implement the "boop" sound:

```
Position currentHeadPosition = body[0];
Position newHeadPosition = null;
SoundPlayer buttonClick;
buttonClick = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Boop);
```

And this is the part where I'd like for the music to play:

```
if (Mic.noMoreMic() == true)
{
    clock.Stop();
    level++;
    levelLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(level);
    gotoNextLevel(level);
    MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.win + "Press the start button to go to Level " + level, "Congrats");
}
```

Ignore the `Properties.Resources.win` thing, I'm trying to project a gif to appear in the popup message but it doesn't work either but if anyone can help me out with it as well, that'll be great!

Comment: Firstly, please ask only one question at a time. Secondly, in the code you have shown, you do not use the `SoundPlayer` you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this blog article by Rod Stephens: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/08/play-an-audio-resource-in-c/

[Copied from csharphelper.com blog post]

First, add the WAV file as an audio resource. 
To do that, open the Project menu and select Properties. Then open the Add Resource dropdown and select Add Existing File. Select the WAV file and click Open.

After you create an audio resource, the program can play it by using a SoundPlayer object. The following code shows the PlayWav method that the program uses to play sound resources.

```
// The player making the current sound.
private SoundPlayer Player = null;

// Dispose of the current player and
// play the indicated WAV file.
private void PlayWav(Stream stream)
{
    // Stop the player if it is running.
    if (Player != null)
    {
        Player.Stop();
        Player.Dispose();
        Player = null;
    }

    // If we have no stream, we're done.
    if (stream == null) return;

    // Make the new player for the WAV stream.
    Player = new SoundPlayer(stream);

    // Play.
    Player.Play();
}
```

Then you can simply call the method when you need to play sound resources.

```
if (Mic.noMoreMic() == true)
{   
    // Your code
    //clock.Stop();
    //level++;
    //levelLBL.Text = Convert.ToString(level);
    //gotoNextLevel(level);
    //MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.win + "Press the start button to go to Level " + level, "Congrats");

    PlayWav(Properties.Resources.boop);
}
```

Comment: You should copy the relevant part into your answer